# Having difficulty figuring out why my implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm is not working?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am using Dijkstra's algorithm to solve the Leetcode Problem **Network Delay Time** (https://leetcode.com/problems/network-delay-time), where I try to find the minimum cost to propagate a signal from a starting vertex to every other vertex in a weighted graph. My code below passes 31/52 of the test cases, but fails the following test case.

I am very confused as to why my code fails, as I believe I am implementing all components of Dijkstra's algorithm correctly. If someone could point me to a possible error point, that would be greatly appreciated:

```
[[15,8,1],[7,10,41],[7,9,34],[9,4,31],[12,13,50],[14,3,52],[4,11,99],[4,7,86],[10,13,57],[9,6,10],[1,7,51],[7,15,38],[1,9,11],[12,7,94],[9,13,34],[11,7,79],[7,6,28],[5,3,34],[2,6,97],[14,1,97],[6,10,90],[12,10,37],[13,3,73],[11,14,7],[15,1,39],[6,5,90],[13,6,43],[6,9,32],[4,6,45],[11,10,2],[2,13,4],[14,15,29],[1,14,88],[14,6,19],[6,2,29],[3,14,72],[1,15,4],[11,5,2],[6,7,56],[8,7,88],[13,14,70],[14,12,58],[14,2,86],[11,3,57],[5,2,56],[3,10,26],[2,11,21],[14,5,54],[5,12,40],[14,4,81],[15,2,99],[5,7,57],[13,12,5],[4,9,60],[12,15,48],[6,14,1],[9,7,44],[13,7,69],[5,13,42],[4,1,7],[11,9,76],[8,1,76],[5,14,29],[2,3,69],[7,3,23],[12,14,28],[11,4,85],[10,1,10],[15,12,36],[1,11,69],[15,10,96],[11,13,69],[7,12,49],[1,2,95],[6,4,46],[8,12,94],[12,4,93],[13,5,31],[12,2,60],[6,1,87],[4,14,20],[5,11,89],[4,15,88],[4,10,21],[1,6,5],[10,8,26],[8,2,51],[3,15,23],[7,2,12],[11,1,47],[2,1,75],[3,8,63],[8,10,19],[6,8,18],[4,2,55],[14,11,80],[10,3,73],[3,5,22],[12,3,61],[1,13,33],[9,3,98],[9,12,69],[15,9,6],[7,13,76],[11,12,22],[11,15,51],[13,15,46],[5,10,58],[1,10,26],[13,4,85],[7,14,58],[5,8,46],[11,6,32],[10,9,41],[9,14,35],[14,13,60],[3,9,97],[2,5,39],[7,11,19],[1,12,27],[7,5,13],[8,4,34],[9,15,25],[5,1,93],[15,13,97],[14,9,35],[8,6,67],[9,5,39],[13,11,35],[7,4,21],[12,9,64],[14,8,8],[10,12,94],[8,9,76],[8,5,71],[2,9,64],[10,14,59],[1,4,74],[7,1,69],[15,5,55],[6,15,80],[13,8,84],[8,13,63],[8,3,91],[10,4,87],[1,5,39],[8,11,0],[1,3,79],[4,5,82],[4,12,87],[3,11,29],[7,8,92],[10,7,77],[6,12,42],[13,2,40],[9,10,13],[4,13,65],[2,4,34],[3,13,44],[2,14,69],[3,4,42],[5,15,98],[14,7,6],[15,3,94],[10,2,37],[15,11,7],[9,2,15],[13,9,66],[4,8,83],[8,15,23],[13,1,50],[6,13,57],[2,10,37],[10,6,38],[2,7,45],[9,8,8],[3,12,28],[3,2,83],[2,12,75],[1,8,91],[4,3,70],[12,6,48],[3,1,13],[5,6,42],[6,11,96],[3,6,22],[15,6,34],[11,8,43],[15,7,40],[9,11,57],[11,2,11],[2,8,22],[9,1,73],[2,15,40],[12,11,10],[15,4,78],[12,8,75],[10,15,37],[13,10,44],[8,14,33],[3,7,82],[5,4,46],[12,5,79],[15,14,43],[10,5,65],[5,9,34],[12,1,54],[6,3,16],[14,10,83],[10,11,67]]
15
8
```

Below is my Java code:

```
class Solution {
    // Dijkstra's Algorithm: 
    // Time: O(|V| + |E| log(|V|)), since I used a min-heap.
    // Space: O(|V| + |E|)
    public int networkDelayTime(int[][] times, int n, int k) {
        // Represent the graph as an adjacency list.
        // Source Node -> set of destination Pairs (Target Node, Travel Time).
        HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> adjacencyList = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>>>();
        for (int[] time : times) {
            int source = time[0];
            int target = time[1];
            int travelTime = time[2];
            
            // Retrieve the existing set of destination.
            HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>> destinationSet = adjacencyList.getOrDefault(source, new HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>>());
            destinationSet.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(target, travelTime));
            
            // Update the set of destinations that can be reached from the current source.
            adjacencyList.put(source, destinationSet);
        }
        
        // Map the distance from source to vertex v.
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> distFromSource = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        
        // Backtracking purposes: map each vertex to the previous vertex along the shortest path.
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> prevVertex = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        
        // Min-heap which stores the vertexes, based on their distance
        // from the source.
        PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>((v1, v2) -> distFromSource.get(v1) - distFromSource.get(v2));
        
        // Edge Case: distance from source to source is 0.
        distFromSource.put(k, 0);
        
        // Initially, the distance from the source to each vertex is infinite (except for source itself).
        // We also haven't figured out any of the previous vertexes.
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i != k) {
                distFromSource.put(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                prevVertex.put(i, -1);
            }
            minHeap.add(i);
        }
        
        // Store the visited vertices so we don't visit them again.
        HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer>();
        
        // While are min heap still isn't empty.
        while (!minHeap.isEmpty()) {
            // Retrieve the closest vertex to the source.
            Integer closestVertex = minHeap.poll();
            
            // Check that the closest vertex hasn't already been visited.
            if (!visited.contains(closestVertex)) {
                // Mark the vertex as visited.
                visited.add(closestVertex);
                
                // Retrieve the distance to the closest vertex.
                int distToClosestVertex = distFromSource.get(closestVertex);

                // Go through the edges to the closest vertex's neighbors.
                for (Pair<Integer, Integer> edge : adjacencyList.getOrDefault(closestVertex, new HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>>())) {
                    int destination = edge.getKey();
                    int travelTime = edge.getValue();
                    int alternativeDist = distToClosestVertex + travelTime;

                    // If we have found a new shortest path to the destination.
                    if (alternativeDist < distFromSource.get(destination)) {
                        distFromSource.put(destination, alternativeDist);
                        prevVertex.put(destination, closestVertex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Find the maximum distance to any one of the nodes.
        int maxDistance = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Integer dist : distFromSource.values()) {
            // We are unable to send the singal to every vertex.
            if (dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                return -1;
            }
            
            maxDistance = Math.max(maxDistance, dist);
        }
        
        return maxDistance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not super familiar with `PriorityQueue`, but I would imagine it doesn't appreciate you changing the priorities out from under it. A quick fix would be to have a separate priority queue element for each discovered arc, prioritized by the proposed distance to the head of the arc.